# what is all_tab_columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

All my table details I found in all_tab_columns , but how it getting  generated
and how dose it works . I am new with oracle some one please explain

Comment: Googling would have done the trick. [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Just read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm):

> `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` describes the columns of the tables, views, and
>   clusters accessible to the current user.

Answer (score 0):

all_tab_columns is a System view.
But as jera said: Google is your friend